# How to render API response in react JS?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api

I am new to react JS and I've been stuck with an issue for quite some time.

So, this is the code,

```
import React from 'react';

class SearchForm extends React.Component {

async handleSubmit(event){
      event.preventDefault();
try{
const url ='/jobs/all/'
const Response = await fetch((url),{
    method: `GET`,
    mode: 'cors',
        headers: { 
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          }});

const filtered = [];

const res = await Response.json();
const Location = this.refs.location.value;
const Category = this.refs.category.value; 

Object.keys( res ).forEach( function( key ) {
    if( res[key].location === Location && res[key].category === Category ) {
        filtered[key] = res[key];}
});
console.log(filtered)
        }
 catch (err) {
    console.error('err', err);}
    };
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
        <form action="/search" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <select ref="category">
            <option value="" defaultValue>Category</option>
            <option value="Ios Developer">Ios Developer</option>
            <option value="Java Developer">Java Developer</option>
            <option value="Marketing">Marketing Generalist</option>
            <option value="Web Developer">Web Developer</option>
            <option value="Python Developer">Python Developer</option>
            <option value="C# Developer">C# Developer</option>
          </select>
          <select ref="location">
            <option value="" defaultValue>Location</option>
            <option value="Lucknow">Lucknow</option>
            <option value="Ranchi">Ranchi</option>
            <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
          </select>
          <button>Find</button>
        </form>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default SearchForm;
```

And this is my response,

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRWxb.png)

I want to render the response.
There are also cases that result in multiple responses and I want to render all of them.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try the below code.

```
import React from 'react';

class SearchForm extends React.Component {
state={
filtered :[]
}

async handleSubmit(event){
      event.preventDefault();
try{
const url ='/jobs/all/'
const Response = await fetch((url),{
    method: `GET`,
    mode: 'cors',
        headers: { 
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          }});

const filtered = [];

const res = await Response.json();
const Location = this.refs.location.value;
const Category = this.refs.category.value; 

Object.keys( res ).forEach( function( key ) {
    if( res[key].location === Location && res[key].category === Category ) {
        filtered[key] = res[key];}
});
this.setState({filtered })
        }
 catch (err) {
    console.error('err', err);}
    };
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
        <form action="/search" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <select ref="category">
            <option value="" defaultValue>Category</option>
            <option value="Ios Developer">Ios Developer</option>
            <option value="Java Developer">Java Developer</option>
            <option value="Marketing">Marketing Generalist</option>
            <option value="Web Developer">Web Developer</option>
            <option value="Python Developer">Python Developer</option>
            <option value="C# Developer">C# Developer</option>
          </select>
          <select ref="location">
            <option value="" defaultValue>Location</option>
            <option value="Lucknow">Lucknow</option>
            <option value="Ranchi">Ranchi</option>
            <option value="Delhi">Delhi</option>
          </select>
          <button>Find</button>
        </form>
        {this.state.filtered.map((data)=>{
           return <div>{data.location}</div>  // you can render here list items
        })}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default SearchForm;
```

Comment: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. This can be ignored right?

Comment: no, don't ignore keys. Anytime you create a list, you need to add keys so react can update the DOM correctly. Just add key={data.id} to your map.(As long as your ID is unique). example : return <div key={data.id}>{data.location}</div>

Comment: Okay, it works! Thank you vipin and @Sir Codes Alot!